# Java OpenGL - How do I make an object rotate with the camera?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, camera

I'm making a 3D game in OpenGL and I need a way to make an object always point towards the camera. It needs to have the same orientation, no matter where you are looking. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You probably want to ask this in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/, not here.

Comment: OpenGL has no such concept called a "camera".

Comment: @immibis This is a rediculous statement that only serves to confuse the asker and complicate the situation. OpenGL may not have a real "camera", but every developer under the sun will know EXACTLY what this person is asking. Its even on the site for crying out loud: https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm Also, he probably does NOT want to check gamedev.stackex because this is a linear algebra question which ties in much closer to OpenGL than generic gamedev. Please try to actually HELP guys!

Comment: @ OP, what you are looking for is called Billboarding when done with a simple quad, but the math is exactly the same for any object. I'm not an expert on this, but I think it can be done by messing with the rotation part of your model matrix. Googling billboarding should help you further, for instance: http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/billboarding_how_to/18011/

Comment: @HenkDeBoer That's not to say that the asker can't use the word "camera", just that if s/he does then s/he should be clear specifically what it means in their program. There are many ways s/he could have implemented a camera and they lead to different answers.

Comment: @immibis "s/he should be clear specifically what it means in their program" Of course he/she should! But that's not what you told him/her! How would he/she know? Your comment was at best pointless and at worst misdirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the inverse camera rotation matrix to the object.